# Python Using (%s) in a string that slo contains a (%)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string that contains a % that I ALSO want to use %s to replace a section of that string with a variable.  Something like

```
name = 'john'
string = 'hello %s! You owe 10%.' % (name)
```

But when I run it, I get

```
not enough arguments for format string
```

I'm pretty sure that means that python thinks I'm trying to insert more than 1 variable into the string but only included the one.  How do I overcome this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `%` in your string using this syntax, by escaping it with another `%`:

```
>>> name = 'John'
>>> string = 'hello %s! You owe 10%%.' % (name)
>>> string
'hello John! You owe 10%.'
```

More about: [String Formatting Operations - Python 2.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

---

As @Burhan added after my post, you can bypass this problem by using the `format` syntax [recommended by Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> name = 'John'
>>> string = 'hello {}! You owe 10%'.format(name)
>>> string
'Hello John! You owe 10%'
# Another way, with naming for more readibility
>>> string = 'hello {name}! You owe 10%.'.format(name=name)
>>> str
'hello John! You owe 10%.'
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know I could escape with a percent, I thought I had to use \ (which didn't work).  If I may, is there a reason that \ didn't work and % did?  Thanks!

Comment: @kroe761 because of the specification for format strings ... ill see if i can find  the link but I think its just on the main python docs page about formaT strings (http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting last item under conventions)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Maxime posted, you can also do this:

```
>> name = 'john'
>>> str = 'Hello {}! You owe 10%'.format(name)
>>> str
'Hello john! You owe 10%'
```